# How to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 to a btrfs partition

Tags: system-installation, btrfs

I've already seen answers in askubuntu, but for old versions.

Disk encryption and hibernation support would be interesting to have.

I'd like to activate btrfs compression and to install root and home into separate subvolumes but in the same partition.

Comment: Can't you just install the tools, make the partition with gparted, then select it when you choose "Something else" partitioning in the installer?

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I didn't know there were so many variants.  I knew only the ISO option.

Comment: Thanks @DanielT, now I'm more specific. I need the desktop version.